# Magento 2 - Dynamic custom pricing for certain accounts

Tags: magento2

I am trying to set up custom pricing for certain customer accounts. For example a user may have a 5% discount off a certain product (I don't want to use catalog rules as there will be hundreds of these, all constantly changing).

I have tried using the `catalog_product_get_final_price` event but it's not working (might be related to [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4027) bug):

```
public function execute( Observer $observer ) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    echo $product->getName(); // this works so I know observer is being called
    $product->setFinalPrice(123.45); // this doesn't work
    return $this;
}
```

Any ideas how best to achieve this?

In M1 I would simply override the `getFinalPrice` method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price`

Is the M1 method still the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a plugin ([Interceptor](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)) on afterGetPrice().
As per Mukesh Chapagains blog post here:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-override-rewrite-block-model-controller-helper-using-plugin-preference/

Comment: Sulman will you please add entire core here I also want similar approach.